# Order of $f(x)=\frac{3}{-2\ln|x|-2\ln|x+3|}$ with respect to $x$

Tags: calculus, limits, infinitesimals

I have $f(x)=\frac{3}{-2\ln|x|-2\ln|x+3|}$ and have to determine the order of this infinitesimal with respect to $x$ for $x\to0$.Then it doesn't matter if we are approaching from left or right because $-2\ln|x|\to+\infty$ and : $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{3}{-2\ln|x|x^\alpha}$$ But it doesn't seem like for any $\alpha$ we can have limit approaching a real number.How can order be determined in that case?

Comment: What if $\alpha <0$?

Comment: If $\alpha\lt0$ we would have $x^\alpha$ in numerator with $\alpha\gt0$.But still I don't get by what kind of logic we can have a real  valued limit for function.

Comment: Can you calculate the limit, for example, when $\alpha=-1$?

Comment: @Botond Yes,the limit is equal to $0$

Comment: Isn't that a real valued limit?

Comment: The point is to get a real valued limit except zero,otherwise limit is 0 for any $\alpha\lt0$